# docker for windows how to access docker daemon from container

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

Im running **Docker Desktop for Windows** (hyper V) and I need to access docker daemon from the container via tcp. It is possible to connect to it from the host like:
`curl -v 127.0.0.1:2375/info` but not possible to access it from a container using my host IP address. Maybe someone knows how to do that or at least how to ssh to that docker vm, for example it is possible to ssh in to it on mac by executing:
`screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty`

Comment: Have you tried to create network and then let your docker containers join that network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured how to do that using `socat` tool which takes docket.socket and proxy TCP calls to it.

So I've launched container with a `socat` which mount `docker.sock` since it is available inside of a VM and expose 2375 port:

```
docker run -p 2375:2375 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock codenvy/socat -d -d TCP-L:2375,fork UNIX:/var/run/docker.sock
```

With that now, I'm able to access docker daemon API through `socat` container.